# Last command in a loop succeeds but exit status is 1

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

So why does the following give 1 when I do `echo $?`?

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo "two">file.txt  
ARRAY=(one three two)  
rc=0  
for i in ${ARRAY[@]}; do  
    echo "grepping $i "  
    grep "$i" file.txt || rc=$?  
done  
exit $rc
```

The last command succeeds since it `grep`s for `two`.
The output is:

```
grepping one 
grepping three   
grepping two   
two  
~$ echo $?  
1
```

I expected 0. Note getting rc as 1 if any command in the loop fails is what I actually want. But I want to understand why this is happening in this case

Answer (score 2):

The last command may succeed, but you only save the exit statuses of failing `grep`s to `rc`.  So if any of the tree `grep`s are failing, your script will exit with a non-zero exit status.

Comment: Ah perfect that is what I need.

Comment: @Jim Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Would `set -e` also achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: @Jim Using `set -e` would make the script terminate as soon as the first `grep` fails to find anything.  If that's what you want, then ok.

Comment: I want that but also to echo some error message to show the reason

Comment: @Jim In that case you can't use `set -e`. You may do `if ! grep ... file; then echo 'error'; fi`.